# Using HTML5 Canvas as document viewer offline

Tags: html5-canvas, documentviewer

I am developing a website on local area network for that i need to display the documents in a viewer, can i use HTML5 canvas as document viewer e.g. (xls, xlsx, ppt, pptx, pdf) etc, it there any library or jQuery library to make offline document viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is not useful in reading Microsoft Office files.

Microsoft has viewers for each of its Office components:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=viewer

And you can just link to .pdf's as long as users have Adobe Acrobat installed:

```
<a href="readme.pdf">Read PDF</a>
```